# How to compute field value during entry creation in Prisma (mongodb)?

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, prisma, prisma-orm

I Use Prisma (v5) to manipulate my Mongodb in NestJS application and can't understand how to calculate fields during DB entry creation.

What i'm looking for is some kind of `onCreate/beforeUpdate` hook or anything else like that.

I have Order and want to calculate `duration` field based on `order.services`

Order prisma scheme (simplified):

```js
model Order {
  id               String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  duration           Int
  services         String[] @db.ObjectId
}
```

Service prisma scheme (simplified):

```js
model Service {
  id          String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  duration    Int
}
```

My order service create method looks like this:

```js
async create(data: Prisma.OrderCreateInput): Promise<Order> {
    return this.prisma.order.create({
      data,
    })
  }
```

How to calculate `order.duration` during order creation/update?

The only idea I have is to fetch all the services before order is created and calculate it's value myself (in order create method, or even earlier on FE side)

But I'm looking for a better solution, as calculated field definition in Prisma scheme, or any oncreate/update hook etc...